# How to add a menu to the window's titlebar

Tags: gtk

|                                  menu                           |<=titlebar

the layout is above ,how can i put the menu in the middle of the titlebar of the gtkwindow?

Comment: The philosophy behind GTK is that you generally shouldn't do these things. It decreases usability and since GTK is so customizable with different rendering engines and themes, there's no guarantee that it will work on every user's desktop.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to disable standard titlebar, and paint one youself.

also, it depends on the OS. when running in mswindows you can make custom titlebar which uses current style (this has nothing to do with GTK).

under X11 you can't normally "extend" titlebar drawing, because it's done by WM in another process.